# How to open files and directories using a single click in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, lxde

Is it possible to configure Lubuntu so that I can open folders or run applications with a single click instead of a double-click? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you should be able to do so. Open PCManFM which is the default file manager. Click on `Edit`, `Preferences`, and then tick "Open Files with Single Click". That's all.

[image: PCManFM preferences]

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to do it through command line (like I had to, due to a small resolution touchscreen and the need to script it for creating additional devices), you can modify the `/home/pi/.config/libfm.conf` file.

Change line 5 of this file from `single_click=0` to `single_click=1`.

You will be required to restart your machine for this to take affect, so I gave it a `sudo reboot` after saving the change.

Comment: This file explicitly says `# Autogenerated file, don't edit, your changes will be overwritten.`, are you sure it should be edited?